# How to go-offline with ALL Android gradle dependencies (maven file structure)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I need to provide an Android software development environment (SDE) for android coding trainings based on Android Studio (AS) and gradle.

I am dreaming of a completely self-sufficient, autarkical  SDE.

The directory structure would look like this:

```
<Root-folder>
   |- Android Studio
   |- android-sdk
   |- gradle-2.2.1
   |- jdk1.7.0_75_64 
   |- jdk1.7.0_75_32
   |- localM2repo 
   |- <git-project checkout>
       |- Android project 01     (with checked-in AS metadata)
       |- Android project 02     (with checked-in AS metadata)
```

This SDE would come along with all aspects you need. It would be fully offline compatible, i.e. you can jump on a train and code for hours without the need to connect to the internet.

I did some scripting and everything works as wanted except for one thing:

Although I can seemingly go-offline with all dependencies, as I will describe in the following, I am unable to run Android Studio against my "went-offline" local maven repository (folder=localM2repo).

Please keep in mind: There is no maven software at all involved, gradle just uses the maven repository structure addressed by

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'file:///<Root-folder>localM2repo' }
}
```

instead of

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}
```

My Android app dependencies typically look like this:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$comAndroidSupport_supportV7Version"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$comAndroidSupport_supportV4Version"
compile "com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:$comGithubMachinarius_preferenceFragmentVersion"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:$comGoogleAndroidGms_playServicesVersion"

compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.1.1'

testCompile "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:$orgRobolectricRobolectricVersion"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$orgMockitoMockitoCoreVersion"

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0'
```

plus I have some buildscript dependencies.

**What does work**

I can "go-offline" with all explicit dependencies. The following snipplet leaches all testCompile dependencies into the my local maven repository. I can do the same for the other scopes (androidTestCompile, compile, ...)

```
task makeLocalM2Repob(dependsOn: makeLocalM2Repoa, type: Copy) {
    destinationDir = buildDir
    into('localM2repo') {
        def fileRenameMap = [:];
        from configurations.testCompile.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.collect { dependency ->
            def groupAsPath = dependency.moduleVersion.id.group.replace('.' as char, File.separatorChar)
            def version = dependency.moduleVersion.id.version
            def newFileName = "${groupAsPath}/${dependency.name}/${version}/${dependency.name}-${version}.${dependency.type}"
            fileRenameMap[dependency.file.name] = newFileName
            dependency.file
        }
        rename { oldName -> fileRenameMap[oldName] }
    }
}
```

**What does not work**

Although it appears to me that all dependencies are available after the leaching, I get the following error on project start inside of AS:

```
Gradle project sync failed. ...

Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.utils.ILogger'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>You are using JDK version 'java version "1.7.0_75"'. Some versions of JDK 1.7 (e.g. 1.7.0_10) may cause class loading errors in Gradle.
Please update to a newer version (e.g. 1.7.0_67).
...
```

I get this error even if I

- delete ~/.gradle/caches
- delete /Android studio/gradle/*
- Press on Android Studio's File/Invalidate caches
- I have fully assured that Android Studio refers to proper JDK, Android-SDK and gralde installation paths.

The error reminds me of [this bug here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73065)

**Questions**

- What else do I need to leach to get a fully offline compatible maven
  repository which can be addressed by gradle to work with Android
  studio?
- Are there any more implicit dependencies I need to add?
- What else can I invalidate to get AS going as I want it?
- Is Android Studio not supposed to work this way?

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that your Java environment is outdated. Try to download a new one on [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

However as far as I know [current Android Studio release](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable) supports offline build, with which a local Gradle distribution and a local maven repository of the build tools are shipped.

Thus I'm concerning about how to integrate them in IntelliJ IDEA because some of the Ultimate functions are very useful. If you or anyone else find it, don't forget to tell me. Thanks

Comment: Well thank you for your answer. But unfortunatelly it does not help. I already use a new Java Version (jdk1.7.0_75) which is newer than the one mentioned in the error ( 1.7.0_67) -see first listing. The offline option of AS works smoothy but you have to get online before switching to offline, which is not what I asked for. I am not referring to IDEA. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: @ChristianKoelle At least the first paragraph is useful :)